Solve cannot find solutions if integer parameters are assumed
This is a very simple toy problem that illustrates the problem.
Start with a fresh kernel.
Quit[]

Make some simple assumptions
$Assumptions = Element[m, Integers] && Element[n, Integers]

The equation to solve;
eq = a c1 L BesselI[(m \[Pi])/a, (a n \[Pi])/L] == 4 V

Solve it for c1.
Solve[eq, c1]

And I get the message

Solve:  This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.  Try Reduce or FindInstance instead.

and it returns the input.
Now if I remove the assumptions and solve:
$Assumptions =.

Solve[eq, c1]
(* {{c1 -> (4*V)/(a*L*BesselI[(m*Pi)/a, (a*n*Pi)/L])}} *)

It works.  If I reapply the $Assumptions, it fails to solve again.  This behavior occurs in versions 13 and abpve.  Earlier versions do not exhibit this.
Does anyone have an idea as to why declaring variables as Integers in a simple equation makes that equation unsolvable?
UPDATE
Sorry for the addition, but I just found a new Solve problem that breaks one of my notebooks.  A fear of zero denominator does not explain this one.
Quit[]

$Assumptions = a > 0 && b > 0

eq = a*b == n*c

Solve[eq, a]
(* {} *)

No warning, just a failure to solve.
$Assumptions =.

Solve[eq, a]
(* {{a -> (c n)/b}} )

With assumptions, b is positive and the denominator cannot be zero.  Without assumptions, the denominator could be.  I would love to report this as a bug, but I fear this is a feature added to Version 13.  Also if we reported a bug every time Mathematica failed to solve an equation, we would be doing little else.
In this case the assumption on b is not the problem.  I only need to remove the assumption on a for Solve to work.  It evidently doesn't like assumptions on the variable being solved for.  I did not assume a>0 to be difficult.  This equation arises from a series of previous calculations in my notebook, some of which require a to be positive.
UseOldReduce does not work in this case.  The only thing I have found that works is:
SetOptions[Solve, Assumptions -> {}]


I have an idea why, but really one ought to admit this is a disappointing backslide (or bug even), and report it to WRI. Seems to affect many two-argument special functions besides BesselI[].

Without assumption, BesselI[ ] is generically nonzero, so it can be put in the denominator. Solve might be afraid of the possibility that BesselI[…] is identically zero under some assumption.

Non-special-function variant: eq = c1  ArcTan[m, a*n] == V; Solve[eq && Element[m, Integers] && Element[n, Integers], c1] -- I suppose it gives a hint in support of @A.Kato's guess. -- So does adding the assumption BesselI[(m \[Pi])/a, (a n \[Pi])/L] != 0 to the OP.

I get the same behavior with BesselJ[] and BesselJ[] has multiple zeros regardless of whether m and n are integers or not.  With  Sin[] and integers I get a warning and a conditional expression.  Like the Bessels, with no assumptions and using Sin[] it solves it with no warnings or conditions even though Sin[] can be zero with non-integers.  I don't understand why integers are special and I don't understand why the Bessels aren't treated the same as elementary functions.

I think the new example might be a different problem. Try Solve[eq, a, MaxExtraConditions -> All] and Solve[eq, a, Reals]. The condition on the variable to be solved for imposes a constraint that seems to require "extra conditions," whatever "extra" means here. (MaxExtraConditions -> 1 is sufficient but MaxExtraConditions -> All produces a simpler answer.) This is not an uncommon problem, I think. Specifying the domain Reals must remove the need for "extra" conditions. I don't have an explanation for that, though.

@MichaelE2  Thanks, that works.  But still I never had these problems with Solve before version 13.

I think I have an explanation now of the change in behavior. See my updated answer. I suggest below that the change came in V12.2 (slightly before version 13).  Does that fit with your experience?

I commented that the assumption BesselI[(m \[Pi])/a, (a n \[Pi])/L] != 0 works, but I wonder what should be considered a workaround.
For instance, this seems an easier way to get a message-free result, without having to figure out which part of the code is the problem:
eq = a c1 L BesselI[(m \[Pi])/a, (a n \[Pi])/L] == 4 V
Assuming[Element[m, Integers] && Element[n, Integers],
 Solve[eq, c1, Assumptions -> True]
 ]

Or if you just want to turn off the integer assumptions:
Assuming[Element[m, Integers] && Element[n, Integers],
 Solve[eq, c1, 
  Assumptions -> $Assumptions || 
     Not[Element[m, Integers] && Element[n, Integers]] // Simplify]
 ]

One can try a legacy solver, which seems a natural move when you run into a backslide:
With[{sysopt = SystemOptions["ReduceOptions"]},
 WithCleanup[
  SetSystemOptions["ReduceOptions" -> "UseOldReduce" -> True];
  Assuming[Element[m, Integers] && Element[n, Integers],
   Solve[eq, c1]
   ],
  SetSystemOptions[sysopt]]
 ]


Solve::fdimc: When parameter values satisfy the condition (V==0&&BesselI[(m \[Pi])/a,(a n \[Pi])/L]==0)||(L==0&&V==0)||(a==0&&V==0), the solution set contains a full-dimensional component; use Reduce for complete solution information.

(* {{c1 -> ConditionalExpression[(4 V)/(
      a L BesselI[(m \[Pi])/a, (a n \[Pi])/L]), 
      a L BesselI[(m \[Pi])/a, (a n \[Pi])/L] != 0]}} *)

The conditional expression seems a nice touch; Normal gets rid of it, if you don't want it.

Update: Response to new example
My first thought was that the new example was a different backslide.  But if we look for a common cause, our attention is drawn to the update to Solve[] in V12.2 that added the Assumptions option to Solve[]. It was implemented to make the following two equivalent:
Solve[eqn, x, Assumptions -> assum]
Solve[eqn && assum, x] (* if $Assumptions = True *)

Or by the default setting, Assumptions :> $Assumptions:
Solve[eqn, x]
Solve[eqn && $Assumptions, x]

In other words, the Assumptions option was implemented as constraints and not as hypotheses Implied[$Assumptions, eqn].
As observed in the OP, the pre V12.2 behavior would be restored (excepting later changes to Solve[]) by the following:
SetOptions[Solve, Assumptions -> True];

To understand the OP's Solve[a*b == n*c, a], we'll analyze a simpler equation with the same problem:
$Assumptions = a > 0;
Solve[a b == 1, a]
$Assumptions = True;
(*  {}  *)

Here is the reduction of the equation:
Reduce[a b == 1 && a > 0, a]    
(*  Re[b] > 0 && Im[b] == 0 && a == 1/b  *)

According to the documentation for Solve[], an extra condition is an equation. So this reduction has one extra condition, Im[b] == 0. This comes from the constraint a > 0, which is taken to imply a is real.  Solve[] filters out solutions with more extra conditions than MaxExtraConditions.  So with the default setting, MaxExtraConditions -> 0, there are no solutions with zero extra conditions, and Solve[..] returns the empty set {}. With MaxExtraConditions set to 1 or higher, we get a solution:
$Assumptions = a > 0;
Solve[a b == 1, a, MaxExtraConditions -> 1]
$Assumptions = True;
(*  {{a -> ConditionalExpression[1/b, Re[b] > 0 && Im[b] == 0]}}  *)

So to get the old behavior of Solve[], set the default option to be Assumptions -> True.  This works on the original problem in the OP.  From this point of view, the first original workaround in this answer accidentally hit the mark, and the "UseOldReduce" method, which might be neat to know about, seems to work by chance.
The core reason for the change in behavior is the addition of the Assumptions option to Solve[].

All good workarounds that should not be necessary.  I will consider putting UseOldReduce in my init file.  I really dislike what Mathematica has done with Solve in recent versions, especially since integer specification has nothing to do with whether a function can be zero or not.

@BillWatts It's particularly strange considering it doesn't seem to matter that the denominator can be zero without the assumptions (something to do with "genericity" perhaps). I just discovered one can use this simpler code: Solve[eq, c1, Method -> {"UseOldReduce" -> True}]. Often certain system options are available through the Method option in a command.

That is good to know but I fear the denominator is not the only problem.  See my update.

Caveat: I can't check behavior pre V14. But the explanation in the docs seemed clear enough. If someone discovers the behavior is not how I described, please let me know. Thanks.

Thanks for the research.  I will probably just turn off assumptions for Solve in any notebook the new "improved" Solve breaks.  This is what the ccgrg people said to do when their package was broken by the new behavior.  And you are most like likely right about it being v12.2 because that is when the ccgrg packages broke.  I no longer have v12.2 to test it though.  Things still work in v12.0.  FYI the ccgrg people also say to add If[$VersionNumber >= 12.2, SetOptions[ValueQ, Method -> "Legacy"]];  I am not sure what that does though.

Adding assumption BesselI[(m Pi)/a, (a n Pi)/L] != 0 solves the problem.
Solve[a c1 L BesselI[(m Pi)/a, (a n Pi)/L] == 
   4 V && {m, n} \[Element] Integers && 
  BesselI[(m Pi)/a, (a n Pi)/L] != 0, c1]


{{c1 -> ConditionalExpression[(4 V)/(
    a L BesselI[(m Pi)/a, (a n Pi)/L]), (m | n) \[Element] 
     Integers]}}


Thanks.  A decent workaround that should not be necessary.
