Solving an n-th degree symbolic polynomial equation
I want to find the positive root of the following function F[x], but using Solve does not work. For this kind of symbolic polynomial equation of degree n, it's relatively easy to solve the roots manually, but it’s quite challenging to solve it with MMA programming. Although, strictly speaking, this is a (2n+1)-th degree equation, it does not affect the essence of the problem.
ClearAll["Global`*"];

(* Define assumptions *)
assumptions = {\[Alpha] > 0, \[Beta] > 0, 
   n \[Element] PositiveIntegers};

(* Define the function F[x] *)
F[x_] := (\[Alpha]/(2 n + 1)) x^(2 n + 1) - \[Alpha] \[Beta] x;

(* Solve for the positive roots of F(x) = 0 *)
solutions = 
 Solve[F[x] == 0 && x > 0, x, Assumptions -> assumptions]

Error message:
Solve::nsmet: The system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

Output:
Solve[(x^(1 + 2 n) \[Alpha])/(1 + 2 n) - x \[Alpha] \[Beta] == 0 && 
  x > 0, x, Assumptions -> {\[Alpha] > 0, \[Beta] > 0, 
   n \[Element] Integers && n > 0}]

I would like to know if there is any general code for solving the roots of this kind of symbolic polynomial equation. Thank you in advance!

Yes, that’s right. I've already edited it. Thank you. @Michael E2

The statement "n-th degree" in the title is not true.

Strongly related, if not duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/306742/1871 Might be related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119934/1871

The two links you provided are indeed relevant to the issue, and I will study them carefully. Thank you! @xzczd

As a function of n, x^n is an exponential function, not a polynomial one. This may not seem significant from an ordinary algebra point of view, but it tends to be significant in symbolic computer algebra, even though things have improved over the years.
Solve[x^n + x == a && n \[Element] Integers && 2 <= n <= 3, x]      (* FAILURE *)

Solve[x^n + x == a && Reduce[n \[Element] Integers && 2 <= n <= 3], (* SUCCESS *)
  x, MaxExtraConditions -> 1]



Is there any general code?

I doubt it, but here's an idea: Simplify the equation by replacing integer exponents with a simple variable. The algorithms seem more robust when the exponents are not composite expressions. It works in the OP's case.
ClearAll[F];
F[x_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_, n_] := (\[Alpha] x^(2 n + 1))/(
   2 n + 1) - \[Alpha] \[Beta] x;
assumptions = {\[Alpha] > 0, \[Beta] > 0, 
   n \[Element] PositiveIntegers};
integerPowerSubs = # -> Unique["k"] & /@
  DeleteDuplicates@Cases[F[x, \[Alpha], \[Beta], n],
    Power[_, p_] /; ! NumericQ[p] && 
       Simplify[Reduce[p \[Element] Integers && And @@ assumptions], 
        assumptions] :> p,
    Infinity]
assumSubs = Function[{pow, k}, (* deduce assumptions on new vars *)
   k \[Element] Integers && k >= MinValue[
      {k,
       Flatten@{pow == k, 
         Select[assumptions, 
          Not@*FreeQ[Alternatives @@ Variables@pow]]}}, 
      Flatten@{Variables@pow, k}, Integers]
   ] @@@ integerPowerSubs
eqn = F[x, \[Alpha], \[Beta], n] == 0 /. integerPowerSubs
Solve[eqn && x > 0, x, Assumptions -> Flatten@{assumptions, assumSubs}]
% /. Reverse /@ integerPowerSubs
(*
 * {1 + 2 n -> k125774}
 * {k125774 \[Element] Integers && k125774 >= 3}
 * (x^k125774 \[Alpha])/k125774 - x \[Alpha] \[Beta] == 0
 * {{x -> (k125774 \[Beta])^(1/(-1 + k125774))}}

{{x -> ((1 + 2 n) \[Beta])^((1/2)/n)}}
*)

Note in the code for assumSubs, no check was made that MinValue[] succeeded. If it fails, you will need to check and decide what is needed in each such case.

Thank you very much for your answer, especially for the insight on extracting the power functions containing symbolic exponents in F and performing substitutions.

Cancelling by x, one succeeds.
ClearAll["Global`*"];
assumptions = {\[Alpha] > 0, \[Beta] > 0, n \[Element] PositiveIntegers};
F[x_] := (\[Alpha]/(2 n)) x^(2 n) - \[Alpha] \[Beta] ;
solutions = Solve[Eliminate[(\[Alpha]/(2 n + 1)) x^(2 n) - \[Alpha] \[Beta] == 0,  x], x];
Simplify[%, Assumptions -> assumptions]


{{x -> (\[Beta] + 2 n \[Beta])^((1/2)/n)}}

Edit. A typo in F[x_]. Also the usage of Eliminate is added.
Addition. No need of cancelling x:
Solve[Eliminate[(\[Alpha]/(2 n + 1)) x^(2 n + 1) - \[Alpha]* \[Beta]*x == 0, x], x]


{{x -> (1/((1 + 2 n) \[Beta]))^(-(1/2)/n)}}

and two warnings.
Addition 2. Even simpler
Solve[(\[Alpha]/(2 n + 1)) x^(2 n + 1) - \[Alpha]* \[Beta]*x == 0, x]


{{x -> (1/((1 + 2 n) \[Beta]))^(-(1/2)/n)}}

Then we take into account the assumptions
Simplify[%, Assumptions -> assumptions]


{{x -> (\[Beta] + 2 n \[Beta])^((1/2)/n)}}


Exactly, it's pretty strange.

@lotus2019: Solve[Eliminate[(\[Alpha]/(2 n + 1)) x^(2 n + 1) - \[Alpha]* \[Beta]*      x == 0, x], x] also works.

Eliminate isn't actually necessary here. The key point is to take the assumptions out of Solve.

Thank you for your answer. Although I am not clear about the reasons behind it, it still solved the problem.
